# Long range connection between devices without internet connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, adhoc

Im trying to control the GPIO of my raspberry Pi with my (android) phone over long range (approx. 100Meters).

What i've tried so far:

- Ad hoc (Failed because android does not support this).
- Bluetooth (does not support range of 100Meters).

Is there any other way to do this without an internet connection? I could use a router and create a network but this is more costly then simply buying a remote.. And i like the idea of controlling the GPIO with my phone.

Comment: You will likely need some additional hardware, for example a moderate range wireless module which you can trivially interface to your pi, and connect to the Android either via USB host or accessory mode, or for a low data rate the headset jack, or less efficiently bridge to via bluetooth or wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Ad hoc, yes Android does not support this officially, but your phone does! An option is therefore to install cyanogenmod, http://www.cyanogenmod.org/, on your phone, which do support ad hoc mode natively.

However, the easiest way would be to simply put the WiFi interface of your Pi in access point mode (Master mode). That way, your Pi will appear as any other AP, and you can easily connect to it. 
For this, you should use hostap:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install hostapd
```

Create a file called hostaptest.conf:

```
#change wlan0 to your wireless device
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=test
channel=1
```

Start hostap:

```
sudo hostapd ~/hostaptest.conf
```

You should now be able to connect to your Pi using the wifi network "test" on your phone.